# Forming a specific colour filled shape in powerpoint when importing a data from excel cell

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am a beginner in programming. I know how to import a data from excel to powerpoint in such a way that when I change the data in the cells in excel, the corresponding datas in the powerpoint changes as well.

But is there a way to create a specific shape (with specific colours) in powerpoint automatically for a range of data imported from excel.

For example, if I type the number 1 in excel, it should go to powerpoint as well and a square box with the colour green should be formed in power point slide with the number 1 in it.
If number 2, then yellow
and number 3 red

Any help would be deeply appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your code it is not possible to give you an example. I would look at

Add shape:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744336%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Once you have the shape, you can color it, add text etc, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744177%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Regards,

HP